# Undefined local variable or method `ie1' for main

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, class, watir

I use watir in Radrails for testing my application. I use two classes in my test, where I also use the variable @ie. Here is the code for the two classes:

First class:

```
class Title
def initialize(title,url,ie)
@title = title
@url=url
@ie=ie
@ie=Watir::IE.attach(:title, @title)  
rescue Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException
puts ("could not find browser")
$r.addtoReport(testReport, "check page element", "FAILED", "Page title " + @title +"   not found") 
else
@ie=Watir::IE.attach(:url, @url)
end
end
```

Second class:

```
class Text_pos
def initialize(text, object,ie)
@text=text
@object=object
@ie=ie
if @ie.contains_text(@text)
puts("Test for " + @object + " passed")
$r.addtoReport($testReport, "check " + @object, "PASSED", "Test for " + @object + " passed" )
else
puts("Test for " + @object + " failed")
puts (@ie.link(:text => /Exception:/))
h= @ie.link(:text => /Exception:/)
$r.addtoReport($testReport, "check " + @object, "FAILED", h.text) 
end
end
end
```

Later in the  test body I execute commands such as these:

```
Text_pos.new("Glossary Of Terms", "login",ie)
Title.new("Company","http://ec2-50-16-62-110.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9100/bobsworld/BPM/Mtebpm000p0001Form.do?resetFilter_action=", ie1)
Text_pos.new("Title", "if page is loaded", ie1)
```

But I get the error - `Test for login passed
BPM/try.rb:106:in`': undefined local variable or method `ie1' for main:Object (NameError)`

Comment: indent the code properly, please.

Comment: At "test body" you do not define ie1 variable, so it is nil.

Comment: You should clean up your code first - the statements @ie=ie/
@ie=Watir::IE.attach(:title, @title) and ie=ie don't make much sense.

Comment: how can i done this, just by adding @ie1 in the beginning of test? And if i do not use class Title this Text_pos.new("Title", "if page is loaded", ie1) works ok. As I understand variable ie1 is defined in class body - @ie=ie, and than I apply to class - set some value - ie1, so that value must be defined

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Željko Filipin's comment:

```
Text_pos.new("Glossary Of Terms", "login",ie)
Title.new("Company","http://ec2-50-16-62-110.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9100/bobsworld/BPM/Mtebpm000p0001Form.do?resetFilter_action=", ie1)
Text_pos.new("Title", "if page is loaded", ie1)
```

You use ie in your first line, but ie1 in the second and third line, which is probably a typo.

Comment: it is not I need operate in different windows